# Generate a exponential distribution with lambda=3

Tags: matlab, exponential-distribution

I have an assignment and now got confused about exponential distribution. The instructions say "service time is exponential distributed with intensity `lambda = 3`."

First I thought generating this is just `exp(3)`, but using Matlab I am wondering if this is right interpretation of the text. Maybe I should use `exprnd(3)` instead?

Comment: Yes, `exprnd`. You probably need `exprnd(1/3)` rather than `exprnd(3)` (intensity is the inverse of average service time). `exp` is just exponential. Note also that [`exprnd`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html) accepts additional parameters if you need to generate an array rather than a number

Comment: Thank. Just what I needed to hear. The assignments had me question everything and I'm not confident enough now to do much without confirmation. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

If the service time distribution, *S*, is exponentially distributed with rate *lambda* = 3, then the average service time is 1/3.

You'll see the [Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) often parameterized by the rate lambda, but MATLAB uses the mean. You can see MATLAB's parameterization [here in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exponential-distribution.html).

To generate service times, one can use `exprnd` directly or use the [inverse transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) for the Exponential distribution.

```
N = 4000;
lambda = 3;   % Rate  Note: AvgSvcTime = 1 / lambda

SvcTimes = exprnd(1/lambda,N,1);  % Approach 1

U = rand(N,1);                    % U ~ Uniform(0,1)
SvcTimes2 = -(1/lambda)*log(1-U); % Approach 2 with Inverse Transform
```

[image: Theoretical vs Empirical PDF]

Note:  You can replace `1-U` with `U` since they are equal in distribution.